# Which cocycles (function classes) compute $H^*(BG, A)$ for $G$ a compact Lie group?

Tags: lie-groups, homological-algebra, group-cohomology

Let $G$ be a compact Lie group.  Given a class $F$ of functions (continuous, measurable, piecewise smooth, $L^2$, bounded ($L^\infty$), polynomial, …) one can define group cochains as in the finite group case and compute cohomology groups $H^*_F(G; A)$.  (I'm mainly interested in the case $A = U(1)$.)

It is well known that for $F$ continuous functions $H^*_F(G; A)$ does not coincide with the Borel cohomology $H^*(BG; A)$ and for $F$ measurable functions we do have $H^*_F(G; A) \cong H^*(BG; A)$ (perhaps with a degree 1 shift).

I'm interested in what's known when $F$ is some other class of functions.  I think [A Cocycle Model for Topological and Lie Group Cohomology](https://arxiv.org/abs/1110.3304) by Wagemann and Wockel might handle the piecewise smooth and piecewise continuous cases (not quite right; see comment by Konrad Waldorf), but I have not understood that paper well enough to be certain.  I'm particularly interested in the $L^2$ and $L^\infty$ and polynomial cases.

The reason usually given, in the $F$ continuous case, for $H^*_F(G; A)$ being unsatisfactory is that it only computes topologically trivial group extensions extensions (those that have a continuous section).  This suggests (very weakly, I admit) that for all of the other classes of functions mentioned above, we do have $H^*_F(G; A) \cong H^*(BG; A)$.  Is this true?

Comment: In Wagemann-Wockel the class $F$ is "smooth in a neighborhood of 1", and the corresponding cohomology, in degree 3, corresponds to general Lie group extensions of $G$ by $U(1)$.